# How do I get the data values just using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

How do I get the data values with just Javascript without using eval?

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged punctuation and atsign",
    "link": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2014-01-09T15:40:57Z",
    "generator": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com",
    "items": [
   {
   .....
   .....
```

Comment: What should happen after the contents inside `jsonFlickrFeed(..)` is parsed ?

Comment: Basically can someone tell me how to parse the data from this url?
http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=punctuation,atsign&format=json

Comment: @DeepakBandi you're dealing with a JSONP response. Please see my answer for guidance. Anyone telling you to use `JSON.parse` is hurting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically can someone tell me how to parse the data from this url? http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=punctuation,atsign&format=json

You're not meant to *parse* that. That's an old-school [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response. One way or another, it has to be evaluated. JSONP is historically used to do [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (cross-origin resource sharing) where proper CORS isn't possible.

You must define `jsonFlickrFeed` within your program, and then

```
<script type="application/javascript"
        src="http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=punctuation,atsign&format=json">
</script>
```

This will cause `jsonFlickrFeed` to be called with the data Object.

**Note:** the term `JSON` is being misused here because `jsonFlickrFeed` is actually accepting a JavaScript Object; not a JSON *string*.

**JSONP Callbacks:** Normally you can configure the name of the callback by passing `&callback=foo` to the JSONP request. I tried this using the flickr URL you provided, but their API somehow functions differently or doesn't support a user-named callback. Check their API and see if you can specify a callback following a sensible naming convention.

---

Here's a fully functional demo to show you how its meant to work. We'll write out 3 pieces of the response data to the console; `title`, `link`, and `modified`. Obviously you can do whatever you want with the data.

```html
<script>
  function jsonFlickrFeed (data) {
    console.log("title", data.title)
    console.log("link", data.link)
    console.log("modified", data.modified)
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript"
        src="http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=punctuation,atsign&format=json">
</script>
```

Here's another demo that displays the images in the `items` attribute

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function makeImage (src) {
    return Object.assign(document.createElement('img'), {src})
  }
  
  function jsonFlickrFeed (data) {
    for (let {media: {m}} of data.items)
      document.body.appendChild(makeImage(m))
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript"
        src="http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=punctuation,atsign&format=json">
</script>
```

In either example, note that I did not have to manually parse anything. There is no JSON here, so there is nothing to parse.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus does my down-vote make sense yet ?

Answer (score -2):

According to your comment below, you have this code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open("GET", "json/flickr.json", false); 
request.send(null) 
var response_object = (request.response); 
console.log(response_object); 
function jsonFlickrFeed(json){ 
   var obj = JSON.parse(json); 
   console.log(obj); 
}
```

The issue is that the response is not 100% properly formatted JSON. The main content is embedded in what appears to be a function call:

```
`jsonFlickrFeed(main content here)`
```

You'll have to remove that wrapper and then you can use JSON.parse on the remaining string:

```
   var response_object = request.responseText.replace("jsonFlickrFeed(", "").substr(0,str.length-1));
   var obj = JSON.parse(response_object);
```

Also, from the code you showed, you have not set up a `load` callback for when the XHR completes.

Comment: Why the down vote for the correct answer?

Comment: How is this wrong?

Comment: There is no JSON in the question. I don't know why you're telling the OP to attempt to `JSON.parse` an object.

Comment: Hey Scott, here is the entire code, but not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "json/flickr.json", false);
request.send(null)

var response_object = (request.response);
console.log(response_object);

function jsonFlickrFeed(json){
   var obj = JSON.parse(json);
   console.log(obj);
 }

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Posting it in the comments makes it very hard to read.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. You're not meant to alter the response from an API before consuming it.